# 1 bit shannon entropy CPU instructions?

Tags: cpu

It has been proved, that the `xor` operator is suitable for entropy accumulation, due to its theoretical shannon entropy of 1 bit.

There are six truth tables with the same shannon entropy, which may be used by crypters.

Which CPU instructions for these truth tables exist already?

```
0 0 = 0
0 1 = 1
1 0 = 1
1 1 = 0 = xor

0 0 = 1
0 1 = 0
1 0 = 1
1 1 = 0 = ?

0 0 = 1
0 1 = 1
1 0 = 0
1 1 = 0 = ?

0 0 = 1
0 1 = 0
1 0 = 0
1 1 = 1 = ?

0 0 = 0
0 1 = 1
1 0 = 0
1 1 = 1 = ?

0 0 = 0
0 1 = 0
1 0 = 1
1 1 = 1 = ?
```

Comment: I smell a homework question... BTW, has a little to do with entropy..

Comment: Different CPUs have different instruction sets. Do you have a specific CPU you are wondering about? or are you looking for something more like what logical operations are necessary here?

Comment: @Gorloth The OP is copying the HW question as is without attempting to understand what he is looking for.

Comment: @Gorloth x86, x86_amd64 and ia-64

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it dumps a request for a solution on us, without showing an attempt at a solution (and it also smells of homework).

Comment: I answered but then deleted because the solution to this is pretty trivial. Agreed, possible homework.

Comment: @ncomputers.org "One of these things is not like the others." IA64 is a completely different architecture from x86.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the present time only exists `xnor`, which is the complement of `xor`.

```
0 0 = 1
0 1 = 0
1 0 = 0
1 1 = 1 = xnor
```

The others truth tables ignores entirely one of the inputs and are not suitable for accumulation of entropy.

Comment: At the present time? Are we likely to discover new 2-input truth tables in the future?